# Can properties file be customised in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. Spring boot has default properties file located in /src/main/resource folder with name application.properties. Now I want not to use the default property.
Suppose if I put two properties file:
1. demo1.properties
2. demo2.properties
How will be those two properties file referred in spring boot?
I am trying to use @PropertySource in main class but it is not working. Is there any other way?
This is my main class::

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.wiley.dnb.controller")
@PropertySource("classpath:log4j.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:services.properties")

    public class DNBMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SpringApplication.run(DNBMain.class, args);

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your main class, or at least the relevant parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need spring profiles!

> Profiles help to have different application configuration for different environments.

At startup of your program, you choose which profile/configuration to use.

Here is a tutorial on this subject:http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-profiles

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

And add @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") into your configuration Class.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate a configuration class with :

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:demo1.properties", "classpath:demo2.properties"})
```

to add properties in the Spring environment.

For example :

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@PropertySource({"classpath:demo1.properties", "classpath:demo2.properties"})
public class MyApplication { ...}
```

Of course these properties file have to be located in the classpath at runtime.

Comment: Hi @David I have added my customized properties what you have mentioned. Do I need add anything in pom.xml?

Comment: Hey. It is the single thing that you need. I use this way with Spring Boot 2 and it works.

Comment: In my application I am not using the default properties. I am using two properties file one with log4j properties and others properties contains the rest service details. But when I run my application with spring boot main class it is not hitting the welcome web page.